# How Can i get cursor on TextBox Automatically in kendoDropDownList like kendoMultiSelect DropDown

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc

[image]*Cursor* [Single DropDown List](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KhxmX.png)

```
        $("#baseServiceScheduleModel_DriverUId").data("kendoDropDownList").enable(true);
```

[image]*KendoMultiSelect DropDownList *
[kendoMultiSelect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lOLMM.png)

```
  $("#baseServiceScheduleModel_HelperUId").data("kendoMultiSelect").enable(true);
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this switching the server filtering? [Server filtering](https://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/dropdownlist/serverfiltering)

The code would be something like

```
@(Html.Kendo().DropDownList()
          .Name("products")
          .DataTextField("ProductName")
          .DataValueField("ProductID")
          .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width:100%" })
          .Filter("contains")
          .DataSource(source => {
              source.Read(read =>
              {
                  read.Action("ServerFiltering_GetProducts", "DropDownList");
              })
              .ServerFiltering(true);
          })
    )
```

Comment: I have tried not working ..cursor was not automatically coming

Comment: Okay, could you please check what is the current active element in document after selecting the dropdown using document.activeElement

Comment: <a role="button" class="k-button k-button-icontext k-grid-Driver driver underline-none" href="#"><span class=" "></span> </a>

Comment: could you please provide full template of the dropdownlist